# Syntax for batchUpdate command with Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm working with Google Script and spreadsheets but I can't seem to get what I need.

So far, I was retrieving data from an API and appending it to the end of the list. However now I am doing an optimisation to only add the new data.

This way I am:

1. Detecting how many new rows I need to add
2. Adding the new data at the beginning.

I am doing this by adding new rows at the beginning of the document (as many as I have new elements) and updating those new rows with the obtained data. However, I am not able to do this last part.

I can't find an example of the correct syntax of Google Sheets API v4 with Google Script and it's difficult to see where I'm going wrong.

Right now what I have is the following:

```
insertRowsInSheet(sheet.cases.id, newDocuments.length, data);
```

Where:

1. `sheet.cases.id`: This is the id of the spreadsheet.
2. `newDocuments.length`: This is the number of new rows I need to add.
3. `data`: This is an array that has the new fields.

The method calls a function that does the following:

```js
function insertRowsInSheet(sheetId, size, data) {
  try {
    const response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
      "requests": [
        {
          "insertDimension": {
            "range": {
              "sheetId": sheetId,
              "dimension": "ROWS",
              "startIndex": 1,
              "endIndex": size+1
            },
            "inheritFromBefore": false,
          }
        },
        {
          "updateCells": {
            rows: {
              values: [
                ["test", "test"],
                ["test2", "test2"]] 
            },
            fields: "*",
            range: {
              sheetId: sheetId,
              startRowIndex: 1,
              startColumnIndex: 1,
            }
          }
        }
      ]}, sheet.id);
    Logger.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`error: ${error}`);
  }
}
```

As `batchUpdate` only works if both methods work, I am now getting the following error:

```
error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[1].update_cells.rows.values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.sheets.v4.CellData), "test"
```

I know that the first part works because if I just run the first `requests`, it enters as many rows as I have new elements. So I go from

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | test1 |
| 2 | test2 | test2 |

to (assuming that I have three new elements)

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| 1 | test1 | test1 |
| 2 | test2 | test2 |

I know there must be some detail I'm missing, but I can't seem to translate the documentation into an example applicable to Google Script.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason you use the api from within apps script instead of the apps script [classes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) itself?

Comment: No. Within the Google Script, I went to services and installed the Sheets (v4) which I thought was the only way to interact with a spreadsheet...

Comment: `rows` should be a array of `rowData` objects and values should be a array of `cellData` objects. See linked duplicate. Also, you can easily search samples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+url%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fsheets%2Fapi%2Freference%2Frest%2Fv4%2Fspreadsheets%2Frequest%23updatecellsrequest)

Comment: Oh! Now, I noticed that this question has already been closed. I deeply apologize that I posted an answer without noticing it. So, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for this, again.

Comment: @Tanaike There's no need to delete a posted answer. See grace period: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402436/how-long-is-the-grace-period-for-answering-closed-questions-and-why-is-it-onl

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for it. After I posted an answer, I noticed the question has been closed. And, I saw the closed time, the closed time is faster than my posted time. So, I thought that when I delete an answer, it follows the time process. By the way, I didn't know that an answer can be posted after the question was closed. Is this not a bug?

Comment: @TheMaster About `grace period`, thank you for the information. I could know for the first time. And, I understood it. So, I would like to reopen it.

Comment: @Tanaike See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402436/how-long-is-the-grace-period-for-answering-closed-questions-and-why-is-it-onl). If none of those reasons in the answer apply to you, it's a [bug], you can report it in [meta]. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible?noredirect=1 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411487/so-rules-on-exploiting-posting-answers-to-closed-questions?noredirect=1

Comment: @TheMaster Although I thought that my post might have been the wrong situation because I got this situation for the first time, I understood it. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, I thought that it is required to modify `updateCells` of the request body.

#### Modified script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId = "###"; // Please set Sheet ID.
data = [["test", "test"], ["test2", "test2"]]; // This is from your showing script.

const response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  requests: [
    {
      insertDimension: {
        range: { sheetId: sheetId, startIndex: 1, endIndex: 1 + data.length, dimension: "ROWS" }
      }
    },
    {
      updateCells: {
        range: { sheetId: sheetId, startRowIndex: 1, endRowIndex: 1 + data.length },
        rows: data.map(e => ({ values: e.map(f => ({ userEnteredValue: (isNaN(f) || f == "" ? { stringValue: f } : { numberValue: f }) })) })),
        fields: "userEnteredValue"
      }
    }
  ]
}, spreadsheetId);
```

Or, when Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) is used, the sample script is as follows.

```
const data = [["test", "test"], ["test2", "test2"]]; // This is from your showing script.
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set sheet name.
const length = data.length;
sheet.insertRowsAfter(1, length).getRange(2, 1, length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

- In above both scripts, the rows of `data` length are inserted from row 2, and the value of `data` is put into the inserted rows.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany)

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike. I will work with this, however, this throws an error as my original data input have int and date types as well. So, i am gettting Invalid value at 'requests[1].update_cells.rows[0].values[11].user_entered_value.string_value' (TYPE_STRING)

Comment: @neteot Thank you for replying. About `this throws an error as my original data input have int and date types as well. So, i am gettting Invalid value at 'requests[1].update_cells.rows[0].values[11].user_entered_value.string_value' (TYPE_STRING)`, I used your showing script. I deeply apologize that I used your showing data. About `int and date types`, I understand `int`. But, I cannot understand `date`. Is that date object? If my understanding is correct, what output format do you want to obtain for the date object? Because the date object cannot be directly used.

Comment: For the date object, I think it might be good to use the string format as well. Just need to detect the int. Need to think about how to do this as I don't want to "hardcode" and index so I want to detect the type first so select from stringValue or numberValue

Comment: @neteot Thank you for replying. About `I think it might be good to use the string format as well. Just need to detect the int.`, I understood it. I would like to modify the script. Could you please wait for it?

Comment: @neteot I modified the script. Could you please confirm it again?

Comment: Jum. not working. Weird tho as the data is `["company name","123","S3","","2022-10-01",334]` so, the only `Int` is the last value, however is throwing: `API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[1].update_cells.rows[0].values[4].user_entered_value.number_value' (TYPE_DOUBLE), ""` for the `""` value

Comment: Now is working by adding this `rows: data.map(e => ({ values: e.map(f => ({ userEnteredValue: ( (isNaN(f) || f == "") ? { stringValue: f } : { numberValue: f }) })) })),`

Comment: @neteot Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that the empty cell is included. So I modified the script. Could you please confirm it, again?

Comment: @neteot Thank you for testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.